# jQuery Mobile list divider using the wrong swatch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I've used the [jQuery Mobile ThemeRoller](http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/) to create a theme for a new mobile website I'm working on. In general the theme works well, but the list-divider that's displayed in the ThemeRoller isn't used in my application.

Here's a screenshot illustrating the problem:

[ThemeRoller problem http://img.skitch.com/20120416-8fbfbu41abrci1ym8uthatfi4e.png](http://img.skitch.com/20120416-8fbfbu41abrci1ym8uthatfi4e.png)

The relevant HTML for the page in question is:

```
<div id="schedule" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li data-role="list-divider">8:00 am</li>
            <li><a href="#session">Welcome &amp; Keynote</a></li>
            <li data-role="list-divider">9:00 am</li>
            <li><a href="#session">Session title displayed here</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've even tried adding a few things I found in the ThemeRoller markup:

```
<li data-role="list-divider" data-swatch="a" class="ui-bar-a" data-form="ui-bar-a">8:00 am</li>
```

This has no effect. No matter what I do, it seems to set the class to `ui-bar-b`. I can live-edit the HTML in Chrome and change `ui-bar-b` to `ui-bar-a` and it looks exactly how I would expect.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this maybe a jqm bug?

Using jqm 1.1.0 and jquery 1.7.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the `data-dividertheme="a"` attribute to your `data-role="listview"` element to force a specific swatch to be used for the divider list-items. By default, if your `listview` is set to theme `a`, then the dividers will be set to theme `b`, so you have to force list-dividers to be the correct theme or you have to build your themes with this in mind.

```
    <ul data-role="listview" data-dividertheme="a">
        <li data-role="list-divider">8:00 am</li>
        <li><a href="#session">Welcome &amp; Keynote</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider">9:00 am</li>
        <li><a href="#session">Session title displayed here</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8aZpQ/ (this demo forces theme `e` for dividers)

And here is the documentation for this: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/lists/docs-lists.html